# Read lock on mongoDB document

Tags: spring, mongodb, concurrency, locking, amazon-sqs

I am creating a trade matching engine which is a Distributed System.
I have one database with two workers if someone placed an order then I m fetching the one document with the matched price. simultaneously while processing the order the previous order server received another request with the same price now I am fetching the same document which is in progress and facing data losses.

Please suggest me any service or MongoDB lock.

I want if the server requests any document from the MongoDB so any other request is not able to fetch the same document.

I am using Spring, Redis Cache, and mongo.

Thanks for help

Comment: Short answer would be make your mongodb Access method as synchronous so only 1 thread will access it at a time and other thread will have to wait. something like this   synchronized public void getLine() { }

Comment: in that server will slow I just want to lock only that document nobody can read and fetch that document.

Comment: 2 things. 1. What will happen if used fires another request for same record. It will reach service class. and call mongo query. you cant control that without blocking method.  2. At mongo level you cant, unless you add some column to the document and mark it as used. and add that filter in query. so that on query no result will return